# Node.js Express return 404 if file not found in only Assets folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create an SPA using `Express` with following code

```
var express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use('/assets', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'www', 'assets')));

app.get('/*', (req, res)=>{
     res.sendFile(path.resolve('www', 'index.html'));
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){});
```

This code works good but the problem is this responds with my `index.html` even when a file is not found in my assets folder. I want it to respond with error of `404 Not Found` if some url is not present in assets folder

I tried using this code after line `app.use('/assets'...`

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("404 Not Found");
});
```

but not working

Comment: You have a function called `app.get("/*", ( req, res ) => {} )` this will always return `index.html` so, it is the expected behavior, change `/*` to something more specific and try again.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar thanks for your reply, I finally figured it out. You can check the answer if want.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with

```
app.get('/*', (req, res)=>{
     res.sendFile(path.resolve('www', 'index.html'));
});
```

Instead, use

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
         res.sendFile(path.resolve('www', 'index.html'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally got the way to solve it

```
app.get('/*', (req, res)=>{
    if(req.path.includes('/assets'))
    {
        fs.access(req.path, (err) => {
            if(err) 
            {
                res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!");
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('www', 'index.html'));
});
```

In the code, I have told to check if the request is about a file located in `assets` folder then check if the file exists, if does not exists then send 404 error with message and just return, otherwise do nothing but return the file.